# What is secure way to use PHP variables in PDO queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, pdo

Yesterday a post a question about how to Update using PDO, and some users told me that the folowing code line is very unsafe, because everybody can modifie my database. Well I undestrand why is not safe but **what should I do with my variables berofe use it in mysql?**

Example of unsafe use:

```
$bdd->prepare("UPDATE `articulos` SET `visto` = `visto` + 1 WHERE `ID` =$_GET['variable'] ");
```

I gues that if a use `$_POST` it still not secure.

And if I do this is unsafe too:

```
$getVar=$_GET['variable'];

$bdd->prepare("UPDATE `articulos` SET `visto` = `visto` + 1 WHERE `ID` =$getVar ")
```

**So what is the safe way to insert variables in SQL queries?**

Thak you.

Comment: You should read up about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @Mureinik I will thank you.